# vb.net WebServices and HTTPS

Tags: android, security, soap, https

We have a web app that uses some WebServices for a companion mobile app (Android). This web app runs on an internal network, as isn't accessible from the "outside". The mobile app accesses these webservices on login (things like checking login credentials, populating a SQLite DB, etc.). Currently, the web app doesn't implement HTTPS, thus making any of the WebService calls "in the clear". This can be a problem, as it checks the username and password, and returns the users full name.
I am looking to implement some security with the username, password, and users full names in order to comply with Google Plays security standards.

Is there a way to be able to send the usernames, passwords, and full names securely between the mobile app and the web app without HTTPS and certificates?

I've looked into hashing and encryption, but those seem to be vulnerable as you would also need to send the keys needed to decode them. I'm not sure how to even begin handling something like this anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: HTTPS is the simplest thing that you could do and solves your problem without the need for another mechanism. Everything stays the same, it's just the transport that changes. Any reason why you don't want to use HTTPS?

Comment: @Bogdan Our current web app infrastructure currently doesn't support HTTPS. In order to allow that simply for a simple mobile data collection app might prove to be more extensive, and costly, than what its worth.

Comment: Then find a way to setup a single endpoint over HTTPS, be it in your existing infrastructure or something new elsewhere as an entry point. Even if you then still need to forward what you get over HTTP,  it will be on the server side which is better than having a HTTP connection between your server and your client.